How to bulk import contacts from a VCF file?
I have a list of contact cards in VCF format, all in a single file. For example:
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//macOS 14.5//EN
FN:Tobias Funke
N:Funke;Tobias;;;
BDAY:1989-05-05
ADR:;;4141 Nope Ave; Portland; OR 11111
TEL;TYPE=HOME:222.222.2222
END:VCARD
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
PRODID:-//Apple Inc.//macOS 14.5//EN
FN:George Michael
N:Michael;George;;;
BDAY:1991-05-05
ADR:;;Nope St; Portland; OR 11111
TEL;TYPE=HOME:111.111.1111
END:VCARD

I can iMessage these contacts to another recipient, and when they open the file, they're able to import all the contacts in it.
But any other way just prompts them to import the first contact; I've tried emailing it as an attachment, uploading it to an S3 bucket, etc.
Is there any other way to get iOS to import a bulk VCF file like this? The contacts list is of everyone in my family and ideally I could email it to them in a way that they could directly import them into their phone.
